# Рендеринг частичных представлений

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

Столкнулся с проблемой рендеринга асинхронных методов. 
Например, имеется шаблон в который мы встраиваем частичное представление

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   @{ Html.RenderAction("PartialInfo", "Profile"); } (1)
</ul>
```

Метод `PartialInfo` является асинхронным

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public async Task<PartialViewResult> PartialInfo()
{
   var user = await userService.GetByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);
   ...
```

Во время рендеринга в строке (1) вылет ошибка

> HttpServerUtility.Execute является заблокированным до окончания выполнения асинхронной операции.

Хотелось бы узнать почему возникает ошибка и почему разработчики запретили асинхронное выполнение методов, для вставки.

---

p.s. Я знаю, что если поменять на синхронную версию, то все будет — ok

Comment: а как вы вообще это себе представляете? вот рендерится значит страница (а она рендерится почти мнгновенно, ибо предполагается что данные уже все готовы), и посередине бац запустился поток для нового экшена, страница потом дорендерилась и ждет пока поток завершится и контент встанет на место? зачем логику переносить во вью? в MVC 6 впрочем подобная функциональность есть во [view-components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components)

Comment: @teran это было вынесено, потому что блок информации есть на каждой странице. Я вынес его в layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Асинхронный рендеринг дочерних action или частичных представлений не поддерживается в ASP.NET MVC. Никак.

Comment: Это было сразу понятно. Хотелось бы узнать чем это обусловлено и какие предпосылки служили для принятия этого решения